# Is there something like DNS for port numbers?

Tags: networking, port

Is there a standard for doing this with port numbers on a machine? That you could send "ssh" or "com.company.my_service" and receive the port configured for this protocol?

I guess it seems odd to me that a service should need to know ahead of time what the port number of a connection should be. With IP addresses, you can know what you want to connect to, or you can do a name lookup.

Comment: IANA maintains the _[Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)_.

Comment: There is `/etc/services` and its API, but that isn't exported beyond the local host. There was also the Sun-RPC `portmapper` service, but only for RPC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the admin of the service has created a [SRV record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record), you can use it to retrieve the port and a few other attributes.  Usually you'll have to do that manually using dig, unless your app is intentionally made to discover ports via SRV record.  I don't know why this practice isn't more common because I agree it would make life a lot more convenient.

Comment: The SRV specification forbids its use other than for protocols that require its use.

Comment: @Alnitak Whatever that means. What it actually says is that it 'SHOULD NOT' be used other than for protocols whose clients 'should' use it, and note that these terms have specific meanings in RFCs. That statement is considerably weaker than 'forbid'.

Comment: @Alnitak the specification does not say that at all.

Comment: @EJP you're correct - I misremembered the exact language, which says "Service SRV records SHOULD NOT be used in the absence of such specification"

Comment: @Alnitak RFC 2782 states no constraint on use cases.   From the context, it simply specifies that a SRV implementation should contain a symbolic name and should take into account the security considerations of the server attributes it is exposing.   https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2782.txt